# How to set generated today date format in spatie/browsershot?

Tags: laravel

Generating pdf with spatie/browsershot I use date class for showing
current date as written here :
https://github.com/spatie/browsershot#headers-and-footers

with code like :

```
   $footerHtml.= '       ...
                        Printed on: <span class=\'date\'></span>
                         ...  ';

    $footerHtml.= '            </tbody></table>             
    </div>';

    Browsershot::html(htmlspecialchars_decode($pdf_content))
        ->showBrowserHeaderAndFooter()
        ->footerHtml($footerHtml)
        ->showBackground()
        ->margins(20, 10, 20, 10)
        ->setOption('addStyleTag', json_encode(['content' => '.block_wrapper {
        background-color : red; !important;
        border: 0px dotted red !important;
    }
```

But the thing is that genarated date is in different format “7/14/2020”, but I use date format like
“14 July, 2020”, which I generate with Carbon formatLocalized method

1. How can I change today format ?
2. Also I see that at the top left corner of generated pdf file I see “7/14/2020” value of current date
   but I did not set it in my code ...

- "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
  "spatie/browsershot": "^3.37",

Thanks!